# How to set value for checkbox via EmbeddedWB.FillForm ? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, tcheckbox

how can i set value for a checkbox via FillForm method ?
I tried these but doesn't work :

```
  W.FillForm('Chkname', 'True');
  W.FillForm('Chkname', '1');
  W.FillForm('Chkname', '', 1);
```

Comment: Where does your `FillForm` come from? I don't recall this as a standard Delphi feature. What add-on unit/library is it in?

Comment: Embedded Webbrowser : http://www.bsalsa.com

Answer (score 3):

Quite late, I know, but I'll try to answer this since it's a good question and since even the current version of the [`TEmbeddedWB`](http://www.bsalsa.com/) doesn't have this feature implemented.

However you can add your own function for doing this; in the following example I'm using the interposed class of [`TEmbeddedWB`](http://www.bsalsa.com/) where I overloaded the `FillForm` function with the version which supports check box and radio button filling.

If you would like to set the check box or select some radio button call this version of function, where:

- FieldName (string) - is the name of the element
- Value (string) - value of the element (can be empty, but in that case the first element of the FieldName will be set; web developers should use name value pairs IMHO)
- Select (Boolean) - if True, check box is checked or radio button selected

Here is the code:

```
uses
  EmbeddedWB, MSHTML;

type
  TEmbeddedWB = class(EmbeddedWB.TEmbeddedWB)
  public
    function FillForm(const FieldName, Value: string;
      Select: Boolean): Boolean; overload;
  end;

implementation

function TEmbeddedWB.FillForm(const FieldName, Value: string;
  Select: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  Element: IHTMLElement;
  InputElement: IHTMLInputElement;
  ElementCollection: IHTMLElementCollection;
begin
  Result := False;
  ElementCollection := (Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementsByName(FieldName);
  if Assigned(ElementCollection) then
    for I := 0 to ElementCollection.length - 1 do
    begin
      Element := ElementCollection.item(I, '') as IHTMLElement;
      if Assigned(Element) then
      begin
        if UpperCase(Element.tagName) = 'INPUT' then
        begin
          InputElement := (Element as IHTMLInputElement);
          if ((InputElement.type_ = 'checkbox') or (InputElement.type_ = 'radio')) and
            ((Value = '') or (InputElement.value = Value)) then
          begin
            Result := True;
            InputElement.checked := Select;
            Break;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

And here a basic example of usage:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WebBrowser: TEmbeddedWB;
begin
  WebBrowser := TEmbeddedWB.Create(Self);
  WebBrowser.Parent := Self;
  WebBrowser.Align := alClient;
  WebBrowser.Navigate('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp');

  if WebBrowser.WaitWhileBusy(15000) then
  begin
    if not WebBrowser.FillForm('sex', 'male', True) then
      ShowMessage('Error while form filling occured...');
    if not WebBrowser.FillForm('vehicle', 'Bike', True) then
      ShowMessage('Error while form filling occured...');
    if not WebBrowser.FillForm('vehicle', 'Car', True) then
      ShowMessage('Error while form filling occured...');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The main point of this post is that you can't use the `TEmbeddedWB.FillForm` as it is, because it sets the `value` attribute of the element what you shouldn't do since the elements like check boxes and radio buttons have the value used for building the name value pairs when sending the form.